# free() to global linked list C

Tags: c, linked-list, global, free

I have a few global linked lists in my program, and a "generic" function that get a pointer to head, and free all nodes:

```
void freelist(list* head) { 
    list* tmp;
    while (head != NULL) {
        tmp  = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

function working good and in the end, the local pointer to the list (head),
became a `NULL`. But a global pointer of the list doesn't changed to `NULL`, and still points to the start of "empty" list (not my values, values after freeing).

Comment: Why would it be NULL?

Comment: Because parameters in C are passed by value. But you shouldn't care about it much as the function is correct otherwise.

Comment: @Yunnosch The last node is supposed to point to NULL. And `head` *will* eventually get there (only the local one, of course).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Of course! And OP even says so explicitly. Blind me totally ignored that little "local" there.... Thanks. Now your comment maks so much sense that I propose to make it an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your last node point to NULL and you need double pointer in freekist to make your global pointer NULL.

In other words if you want to change global head to NULL give the address of globalHead to freelist function, to do that you need double pointer.

You can make call to freelist like below.

```
freelist(&globalHead);
```

And your freelist definition goes like below.

```
void freelist(list **head)
         { 
              list* tmp; 
              if(head ==NULL)
              return;

              while(*head!=NULL)
             {
                 tmp=*head;
                *head=(*head)->next;
                free(tmp); 
             }
         }
```

Comment: So in other words,  if you want to change a global pointer's value from a function, give the function a pointer to that pointer.  Then it can change that pointer to NULL .

Answer (score 2):

It's debatable whether it's worthwhile trying to set the pointer to NULL after free'ing. Because you shouldn't be touching the `head` pointer after free'ing the list anyway and there's nothing wrong with `head` pointing to the "old value" - using it after free is undefined behaviour.

Leaving that aside, if you do want to set it to NULL by the free'ing function, you'll have to pass a pointer to `head` as in:

```
void freelist(list **head)
{ 
    list* tmp, *p = *head;
    while(p != NULL){
        tmp = head;
        p = p->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
    *head = NULL;
}
```

and call it as:

```
freelist(&head); // Assuming 'head' is of type 'list *'.
```

This is because everything in C is *passed by value*. That's why only the local copy of the `head` in `freelist` becomes NULL but not the one you passed to it.